# C, Global Variable change isn't kept outside the function

Tags: c, struct, stack, malloc, global-variables

In the pop() function i am trying to change the value of the Last global variable. It works fine in the push(n) function, while in the pop() one it changes it inside the function (verifying it with prints) but then it resets to the previous value just after leaving the method. Can't get my head around it.

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *Stack;
int Last = -1;

void make_empty( void ){
    free(Stack);
    Last = -1;
    Stack = NULL;
    //Stack = malloc(4);
    return;
}

int is_empty( void ){
    if (Last == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int top( void ){
    if (is_empty()) {
        printf("La pila è vuota");
    }
    return Stack[Last];
}

int pop( void ){
    if (is_empty()) {
        printf("La pila è vuota");
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = Stack[Last];
    printf("last: %d\n", Last);
    Stack = realloc(Stack, (--Last+1)*sizeof(int));
    printf("last: %d\n", Last);
    return temp;
}

void push( int n ){
    Stack = realloc(Stack, (++Last+1)*sizeof(int));
    Stack[Last] = n;
    return;
}

void print_stack( void ){
    printf("last: %d\n", Last);
    for (int c=0; c<=Last; c++)
        printf("%d ", Stack[c]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If `Last == -1` then what do you think `++Last*sizeof(int)` will be?

Comment: Ok I corrected those by putting `(--Last+1)*sizeof(int)` and `(++Last+1)*sizeof(int)`, i assigned Last to -1 since i also needed it for position, but the main problem persists, the variable Last just keep assigning to the previous value when the pop func ends

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the stack contains undefined behavior.

For example initially `Last` is equal to `-1`.

```
int Last = -1;
```

then in the `push` operation

```
void push( int n ){
    Stack = realloc(Stack, ++Last*sizeof(int));
    Stack[Last] = n;
    return;
}
```

there is allocated memory of the size equal to `0` because `++Last` is equal to `0`. You may not change the memory allocated with the size equal to `0`.

A similar problem exists for the method `pop`. When `Last` is equal to `0` then in this statement

```
Stack = realloc(Stack, --Last*sizeof(int));
```

the expression `--Last` is equal `-1` that is converted to the maximum value of the type `size_t` due to the type of the operand `sizeof(int)`.

You could write for example the method `push` the following way

```
void push( int n ){
    Stack = realloc(Stack, ( ++Last + 1 ) *sizeof(int));
    Stack[Last] = n;
    return;
}
```

And in the `pop` method you could use

```
if ( Last == 0 ) 
{
    free( Stack );
    Stack = NULL;
}
else
{
    Stack = realloc(Stack, ( Last *sizeof(int));
}

--Last;
```

Pat attention to this if statement

```
if ( Last == 0 ) 
{
    free( Stack );
    Stack = NULL;
}
```

when the stack is empty all allocated memory must be freed and `Stack` must be set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating enough space for your stack.

At the start `Last` is -1.  Then you push an element to the stack and allocate space:

```
Stack = realloc(Stack, ++Last*sizeof(int));
```

After the increment, `Last` is 0.  So you're allocating `0*sizeof(int) == 0` bytes.  You then write to `Stack[Last]` which doesn't exist.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case manifests by causing a variable to change when you don't expect.

Since `Last` contains the last valid index, you want to add 1 to this to get the proper number of elements to allocate:

```
Stack = realloc(Stack, (++Last + 1)*sizeof(int));
```

You make a similar mistake when popping:

```
Stack = realloc(Stack, --Last*sizeof(int));
```

You also need to add 1 here:

```
Stack = realloc(Stack, (--Last + 1)*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected those by putting `(--Last+1)*sizeof(int)` and `(++Last+1)*sizeof(int)`, i assigned Last to -1 since i also needed it for position, but the main problem persists, the variable Last just keep assigning to the previous value when the pop func ends

Comment: @otoni24 Then you must be doing something else wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run as-is to reproduce your problem.